# how to pull the word in a string and put into array pandas

Tags: python, arrays, regex, string, pandas

I am attempting to use regular expressions to pull just the alphabet portion of a string, and put it into an array. For example,

```
Target_column

ABC1234-332DER
1334-GGH-21WW
GG43--222EER

Desired_output

[ABC, DER]
[GGH,WW]
[GG,EER]
```

I have a regular expression code that is not generating the results I would like

```
df['target_column'] = df['desired_column'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=True)
```

This yields the following output:

```
0   ABC1234-332DER  ABC
1   1334-GGH-21WW   GGH
2   GG43--222EER    GG
```

What is the proper regex syntax to get the desired column?

Comment: Why `\w`? (Numbers are word characters too - if you don't want numbers, don't use `\w`)

Comment: just updated my post. thanks! still errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), and then unstack the values and convert to list:

```
df['desired_column'] = (df.Target_column.str.extractall('([a-zA-Z]+)')
                        .unstack()
                        .values.tolist())

>>> df
    Target_column desired_column
0  ABC1234-332DER     [ABC, DER]
1   1334-GGH-21WW      [GGH, WW]
2    GG43--222EER      [GG, EER]
```